# getting error passing a pointer to file

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm still learning C, so please bear with me.  I'm getting an unusual error passing a pointer to file back from a function to `main()`.

The code follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "FilMst5.c"

int main() 
{
    FilMstFilPtr = Opn("\\temp\\test.file", "wb");  // <- error occurs here
    printf("filptr=0x%p\n", FilMstFilPtr);  
    return 0;
}

//****************************************************************************** 
//  Open a file  
//****************************************************************************** 
FILE * Opn(char PthNam[], char OpnMod[]) 
{
FILE    * FilPtr = NULL;

    errno = fopen_s(&FilPtr, PthNam, OpnMod);
    if (errno != 0) {
        printf("%s\n", PthNam);
        perror("Could not open file");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("file opened for mode %s\n", OpnMod);
    return FilPtr; 
}
```

The FilMst5.c include file is:

```
#pragma once

typedef struct {                                            
    int                 FilRRN;
    unsigned long long  FilOfs;
    unsigned long long  FilID;
    char                FilDir[10 + 1];
    char                FilNam[10 + 1];
    char                FilNamLcs[10 + 1];
    char                FilDirLcs[10 + 1];
    char                FilTypLcs[10 + 1];
    char                FilAtr[10 + 1];
    char                UsrID[10 + 1];
    char                SysID[8 + 1];
    char                FilSrcDir[10 + 1];
    char                FilSrcMbr[10 + 1];
} FilMstStc;
FilMstStc   FilMst;


typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL1OfsStc;
FilMstL1OfsStc  FilMstL1Ofs[250000000];

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL1Stc;
FilMstL1Stc FilMstL1Key, FilMstL1SchKey;


typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL2Stc;
FilMstL2Stc FilMstL2[250000000];


typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  FilSID;
} FilMstL3Stc;
FilMstL3Stc FilMstL3Key, FilMstL3SchKey;


typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL4Stc;
FilMstL4Stc FilMstL4[250000000];


FILE    * FilMstFilPtr;

FILE * Opn(char PthNam[], char OpnMod[]);

void WrtFilMstRcd(void)
{
}
```

The error I get, on returning from the function is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000000013FA41971 in CrtFil5.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation writing location 0x000000012E0FEA08.
```

The output I expected to get would be:

```
file opened for mode wb
filptr=0x00000000########  <- pointer to file
```

I only get the first line, so there's some error between the return statement in the function and the actual return.

What is really strange is that if you delete any of the lines in the FilMst5.c include file, the program works as desired.  But I have a larger program that uses the routines and I can't delete random lines to try to get it working.

What could cause this problem?

I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 with Update 1, compiled in x64 mode.  Please let me know any additional info that would be helpful.

Comment: Don't include `*.c` files!

Comment: and I think it has something to do with the *huge* arrays allocated..

Comment: Run it with the debugger and it will tell you (and us) _where_ the crash occurs.

Comment: Thank you.  The include file isn't really a .h file, and I haven't had any problems including .c files in the past.  Like I said, when I comment any lines in the include file, like those of the arrays, the program works.  The larger program worked up until 3 days ago when I changed something and it started not working.  It's taken me this long to narrow the problem down to the smallest size that reproduces the error.

Comment: I will repeat: Don't include `*.c` files. Regardless of can you some how make it work or not. By "any line" do you mean blank lines as well? Or the ones declaring arrays only?

Comment: Supporting @EugeneSh. If you `#include` a `.c` file, your project is set up wrong. Split the file into a header and an implementation (i.e. `.c`) file.

Comment: @ Michael Waltz:  Well, I consistently got this message unless I commented out a line in the FilMst5.c include file.  But I just now executed the program by "Start Debugging" and the program worked okay.  I then tried the option to "Start  Without Debugging" and it still worked okay, when before I got the error message.  I tried executing the larger program with "Start Debugging" and still got the following message: `Exception thrown at 0x000000013F10942F in CrtPF.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000012E7CDBE8.`.

Comment: @Eugene Shand and Olaf:  Thank you.  Perhaps you are right.  My thinking was that I have common subroutines that several programs use.  I don't know how to create a shared library DLL, so all I can do to avoid repeated copying is include the common .c code.

Comment: @EugeneSh:  I only commented out actual lines of code, not blank lines.  The program worked even if I only commented out a definition of a field in the FilMstStc structure.  It also worked if I commented out the large arrays.

Comment: @J.Toran You can use the same C file in different programs, if you "add" it to your project as a "source file" without copying, but only by pointing to it as "source directory". But I still think you have memory issues here. Try reducing the array sizes.

Comment: And as a general thing: If you don't know how to do something correctly, don't work it around incorrectly. Just learn how to do it correctly.

Comment: @EugeneSh.:  Thank you.  I'm not sure how to add the common C code as a source file, but I will give it a try.  Also I **decreased** the size from 250,000,000 to 100,000,000 and I'm getting `Error LNK1248 image size (941E1000) exceeds maximum allowable size (80000000) CrtPF C:\$SmpSysLib\$QsysS\CrtPF\CrtPF\LINK 1`.  I will work on it some more.

Comment: Better to obtain memory from `malloc` or `calloc` than use such large static arrays.

Comment: I am starting to think you are hitting the array size limit of the compiler

Comment: @EugeneSh.:  I decreased the arrays sizes to 10,000,000 and the program compiled okay and ran until I got a debug assertion failed message.  I probably did something stupid.  Also, I did an "Add Existing Item" from the Project menu and the .c files showed up as source files, but then the program wouldn't compile with strange error messages.  I'll have to work on it.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  You're right.

Comment: I notice you have hard coded the array lengths. How does that impact on the code's array indexing  when you change them? I would expect to see `#define ARRLEN 250000000` to be used for array definitions, loop control, bounds checking, etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  Right again.  Normally I would but hadn't for this test program.

Comment: @user3629249 they are both in the included C file. Which has been frowned on in comment, and the resulting confusion also caused a similar answer to your comment  to be made and then deleted.

Comment: this file: `FilMst5.c`, (which should be named: `FilMst5.h`) does not define the variable: `FilMstFilPtr`.   Also, variable declarations should never be in a #include'd file, because if that that file is #include'd in more that one place, then the compiler will raise 'flags'  about duplicate definition of variables.  a function+body should never be #include'd unless that function has the `inline` modifier.

Comment: @user3629249 I repeat: "FilMst5.c" ***does*** contain `FILE * FilMstFilPtr;` and `FILE * Opn(char PthNam[], char OpnMod[]);`. See what chaos it brings?

Comment: regarding this comment: *My thinking was that I have common subroutines that several programs use. I don't know how to create a shared library DLL, so all I can do to avoid repeated copying is include the common .c code* rather than #including the *.c file,  just use function prototypes.  (which probably should be in a header file) The linker will take care of the rest of it.

Comment: @user3629249 and Weather Vane:  I can't manage to add the file to the project, rather than including it.  [So I asked here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773522/trying-to-understand-simple-task-of-adding-files-to-vs-projects)

Comment: I don't know if anyone is still following these comments, but I was wondering if `typedef`s belong in the header or the C code?  I take it they go in the header.

Comment: if the resultant type will be used in more than one source file, then they belong in the header file.  if the usage is limited to a single source file, then it is better to keep the typedef local to the source file.

Comment: @user3629249 and Weather Vane and others:  Thanks for all your help.  I'm still a beginner so I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strongly suggest writing code that is 'portable', even if it is only going to be used in a windows environment:

This is accomplished by prefixing the file with:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

then using the functions from the standard C libraries rather than the functions from the `windows.h` header/libraries

the header file: FilMst5.h contents should be:

```
#pragma once

typedef struct {                                            
    int                 FilRRN;
    unsigned long long  FilOfs;
    unsigned long long  FilID;
    char                FilDir[10 + 1];
    char                FilNam[10 + 1];
    char                FilNamLcs[10 + 1];
    char                FilDirLcs[10 + 1];
    char                FilTypLcs[10 + 1];
    char                FilAtr[10 + 1];
    char                UsrID[10 + 1];
    char                SysID[8 + 1];
    char                FilSrcDir[10 + 1];
    char                FilSrcMbr[10 + 1];
} FilMstStc;

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL1OfsStc;

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL1Stc;

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL2Stc;

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  FilSID;
} FilMstL3Stc;

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long  RcdOfs;
} FilMstL4Stc;

FILE * FilMstFilPtr;

FILE * Opn(char PthNam[], char OpnMod[]);

inline void WrtFilMstRcd(void)
{
}

// enable other files to access the variables declared in main.c
extern FilMstStc   FilMst;
extern FilMstL1OfsStc  FilMstL1Ofs[250000000];
extern FilMstL1Stc FilMstL1Key;
extern FilMstL1Stc FilMstL1SchKey;
extern FilMstL2Stc FilMstL2[250000000];
extern FilMstL3Stc FilMstL3Key;
extern FilMstL3Stc FilMstL3SchKey;
extern FilMstL4Stc FilMstL4[250000000];
extern FILE    * FilMstFilPtr;
```

---

the file: (lets call it `main.c`)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include "FilMst5.h"

FilMstStc   FilMst;
FilMstL1OfsStc  FilMstL1Ofs[250000000];
FilMstL1Stc FilMstL1Key;
FilMstL1Stc FilMstL1SchKey;
FilMstL2Stc FilMstL2[250000000];
FilMstL3Stc FilMstL3Key;
FilMstL3Stc FilMstL3SchKey;
FilMstL4Stc FilMstL4[250000000];
FILE    * FilMstFilPtr;


int main( void )
{
    FilMstFilPtr = Opn("\\temp\\test.file", "wb");  // <- error occurs here
    printf("filptr=0x%p\n", FilMstFilPtr);
    return 0;
}

//******************************************************************************
//  Open a file
//******************************************************************************
FILE * Opn(char PthNam[], char OpnMod[])
{
FILE    * FilPtr = NULL;

    errno = fopen_s(&FilPtr, PthNam, OpnMod);
    if (errno != 0) {
        printf("%s\n", PthNam);
        perror("Could not open file");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("file opened for mode %s\n", OpnMod);
    return FilPtr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying this out.  I got a compile warning message `Warning C4603 '_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS': macro is not defined or definition is different after precompiled header use` so I commented that line out.  Now I'm getting something I've never seen before.  On the opening brackets of both `main()` and `Opn` I get the following message:  `Error C2601 'main': local function definitions are illegal`

Comment: Daggone, I just copied and pasted wrong.  I did get a `Error C2086 'FILE *FilMstFilPtr': redefinition` message but I just commented one out and it worked fine.

Comment: the `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` can be placed in  "Preprocessor Definitions" in the project settings/properties, then you can use the standard C library functions without getting any warnings

Comment: the 'local functions' error message indicates some copy./paste error.   I compiled the code, on ubuntu linux, using gcc, added `#include <errno.h>` and commented out the `#include <stdafx.h>` (which only helps subsequent compiles) and the only problem is the call to `fopen_s()` which is a non-portable function from MSDN  Suggest posting your new files, as an additional text edit of the question.

Comment: Like I said, I just copied and pasted wrong.  It worked fine.  And I checked it as the correct answer.