# Trying to understand simple task of adding files to VS projects

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

As I said before, I'm still learning.  Per the comments in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770370/getting-error-passing-a-pointer-to-file), I'm trying to add a file into an existing project, rather than including it.  The source code is listed in the previous post.  I used [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx) to add the file to the project.  I renamed the include file from FilMst5.c to FilMst5.cpp to avoid the following error:

`C1853  'x64\Debug\CrtFil5.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)`

I also added `#include "stdafx.h"` to prevent another compile error message.  When I tried to compile the project files, I got 2 messages `'FilMstFilPtr': undeclared identifier` and another message `'Opn': identifier not found`.  So I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't really understand how it's supposed to work in order to fix it.  Can someone tell me the correct way to do this?

The C code previously compiled fine even though it has a .cpp extension, the way Visual Studio does things.

Comment: I suggest starting a new project to get rid of old stuff. And don't rename a .c file .cpp unless it really is C++.

Comment: I also suggest deleting `#include "stdafx.h"` and adding `#include <stdio.h>` and so on, as required. Unless your project takes an age to compile.

Comment: Keep it simple. Make a "Hello World" program with two modules, one of which contains and/or prints that string. You don't need to make a DLL. The linker should combine the separate compilation units into a single .exe.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  Thank you again.  If I don't `include "stdafx.h"` I get the following message:
`Error C1010 unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?`  Otherwise it worked okay.  I just didn't know what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for anyone wasting time on this question.  I just needed the necessary declarations in a header file, and the linker took care of the rest of it.